# Lost data at CP -r <from source> <To destination> How to do Recovery

Tags: linux, hard-drive, data-recovery, ubuntu-12.04

I took a backup into external hard disk and moved all of them to my new Ubuntu machine location /tmp which is near around 100 GB. And I moved via command prompt

```
cp -r /tmp /home
```

The folder into my /home folder. But my /home location had low space. But source folder size is 7.7 GB and designation /home is 4 GB. I forget to notice that at the time of coping. When i start coping I got some low space message and the action stopped.

After error message I couldn't see my source files. Please forgive me if make any mistakes in this posting.

Answer (score 1):

This is potentially grotty, and I don't think I have the whole story here. There's a few elements here that I'm potentially unsure of.

You're copying, not moving - that's *typically* non destructive, which had me confused. Then I realised you're using [tempfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs), which is typically volatile storage - basically swap and ram,

You have two problems here which one of which might have caused your problem [moving large files uses swap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92206/copying-large-file-causes-excessive-swap) (and tmpfs also uses swap - I'm unsure if thats what caused the deletion), and the other makes it impossible to recover - you had the file in *volatile storage* which isn't actually meant to keep files in the long run, and may or may not be on disk.

There's a few elements I'm missing - /tmp/ seems unreasonably huge if its what I think it is, whether you reformatted it, and what actually happened to the files. Unless proven wrong though, I'm convinced the files can't be recovered.

Comment: For the record, `/var/tmp` is the temporary location that persists across reboots and is backed by non-volatile storage (normally).

Comment: Hi Bob,
I looked over in /var/tmp also there is nothing ..

Comment: @sivashanmugam There wouldn't be anything unless you put it there. My point is `/tmp` tends to truncate after a certain size (sometimes just a few megabytes, sometimes *could* be gigabytes), so you should never use it as a temporary location for these transfers - for the *future*, use `/var/tmp` instead. It's already too late for this time.